# I want to remotely control a wall switch in my house with my cell phone

Tags: smart-switch

I have two wall switches in my garage that control outlets under my eaves. I have plugged into the outlets heated cables for melting snow in the gutters and on the overhang. I have been using these for 10+ years manually, but I find I am away from the house frequently when it snows and need to find someone to manually turn on the switches for me.

I want to be able to control these switches using my cell phone when I am away from my house.
There is one breaker for each switch and they are each 20 amp. I assume the switches are each 20 amp, and they are both GFI.

Is there any type switch that can be used to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in another answer, there are a lot of products available. However, most are geared towards lighting. Residential lighting loads are low, especially in the LED era. In addition, electronic switches don't handle large loads as well as mechanical switches. The result is limits that you need to adhere to on order to avoid premature failure or damage.

I would generally compare a heating cable to an equivalent incandescent bulb based on power (watts). It doesn't matter what the circuit is rated for (by definition it will be 15A or 20A), what matters is the actual load. Since some people have 15A circuits and some people have 20A circuits, these types of off-the-shelf heaters will generally use a maximum of 15A x 0.8 = 12A x 120V = 1,440W. So unless you know otherwise, that's the target you need to support in any switches.

A couple of examples. No connection to any of the vendors or manufacturers, just semi-randomly searching through [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/). (FYI, you *must* make sure that you get devices that are UL or ETL listed. Cheap off-shore junk can fail in very unexpected ways, which your insurance company won't be happy with.)

- [TP-LINK Smart Wi-Fi Light Switch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/TP-LINK-Smart-Wi-Fi-Light-Switch-HS200/301461305)

The specifications say "15A" but the only power rating given is "600W incandescent". Which implies a 5A/600W maximum. I wouldn't trust it for more than 600W without more information from the manufacturer.

- [Leviton Decora Smart with Z-Wave Technology](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-Smart-with-Z-Wave-Technology-15-Amp-Switch-White-Light-Almond-R51-DZ15S-1RZ/300261797)

This is more like it! 600W CFL and LED, 1800W incandescent and 15A resistive load. That should handle anything except the max. continuous load on a 20A circuit (16A).

There are plenty of other choices. But read the specifications carefully before you buy anything. Also avoid anything with a dimmer function - that's generally not going to play well with anything except lighting.

GFCI can be provided either at the breaker or at the receptacle. If it is at the receptacle and has worked OK with a mechanical switch, it should work OK with a good quality electronic switch. However, if you currently have a combination GFCI/switch device then you will need to have a separate GFCI from the electronic switch as you generally can't get an electronic (remote control/etc.) switch combined with a GFCI.

Answer (score 0):

Too many returns to list here and product recommendations are more or less in violation, but...

A search for "internet controlled light switch" provides many options. In the return listing, I see references to Alexa, Google and some obscure references likely related to smart houses as well as smart phones.

Adding "gfci" to the mix throws a wrench in the works, however. I found no conclusive links with that term as part of the search.

I use a product manufactured by BN-Link that is smart phone capable, but requires that I have connectivity to my home wifi network, not something remote network accessed.